# Supplying Data to WMI by Writing a Provider

Tags: c++, windows, wmi, provider

I am new to c++ and I am trying to develop a WMI provider in windows. After few searches I have come across a documentation of MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/supplying-data-to-wmi-by-writing-a-provider) I have followed all the steps and finally used the same example they have given, still it not go beyond the DllRegisterServer method after I register the *dll* using *regsvr32* command. But it says after registering the *dll* wmi instance should be there.

My guess is I am missing something from the documentation or I am not understanding basic of Dll.

What I want is to call *Initialize* method in *InstProv* file after the registration process is success.

Please excuse me if this is a lame question, since I could not find much resources under WMI Providers thought of raise my problem here.

Here is my *DllRegisterServer* method

```
STDAPI DllRegisterServer(void)
{   
    char       szID[128];
    WCHAR      wcID[128];
    char       szCLSID[128];
    TCHAR       szModule[MAX_PATH + 1];
    const char * pName = "WMI Sample Instance Provider";
    const char * pModel = "Both";
    HKEY hKey1, hKey2;


    // Create the path.

    memset(wcID, NULL, sizeof(wcID));
    memset(szID, NULL, sizeof(szID)); 
    StringFromGUID2(CLSID_instprovider, wcID, sizeof(wcID)/sizeof(WCHAR));
    wcstombs(szID, wcID, sizeof(szID)); 
    StringCbCopy(szCLSID, sizeof(szCLSID), "Software\\classes\\CLSID\\");
    StringCbCat(szCLSID, sizeof(szCLSID), (LPCTSTR)szID);

    // Create entries under CLSID

    LONG lRet = RegCreateKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
                                szCLSID, 
                                0, 
                                NULL,
                                REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, 
                                KEY_WRITE, 
                                NULL, 
                                &hKey1, 
                                NULL );
    if (lRet != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    lRet = RegSetValueEx(hKey1, NULL, 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE *)pName, strlen(pName)+1);
    if (lRet != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey1);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    lRet = RegCreateKeyEx( hKey1, "InprocServer32", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hKey2, NULL );
    if (lRet != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey1);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    memset(&szModule, NULL, sizeof(szModule));
    GetModuleFileName(ghModule, szModule, sizeof(szModule)/sizeof(TCHAR) - 1);

    lRet = RegSetValueEx(hKey2, NULL, 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE *)szModule, strlen(szModule)+1);
    if (lRet != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey2);
        RegCloseKey(hKey1);
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    
    lRet = RegSetValueEx(hKey2, "ThreadingModel", 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE *)pModel, strlen(pModel)+1);
    if (lRet != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey2);
        RegCloseKey(hKey1);
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    RegCloseKey(hKey1);
    RegCloseKey(hKey2);
    return NOERROR;
}
```